# Error while uploading picture with the requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to implement the [Yandex OCR translator tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vyL.png) into my code. With the help of Burp Suite, I managed to find that the following request is the one that is used to send the image:

[image: request photo]

I'm trying to emulate this request with the following code:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
files={
    'file':("blob",open("image_path", 'rb'),"image/jpeg")
    }

#(<filename>, <file object>, <content type>, <per-part headers>)
burp0_url = "https://translate.yandex.net:443/ocr/v1.1/recognize?srv=tr-image&sid=9b58493f.5c781bd4.7215c0a0&lang=en%2Cru"


m = MultipartEncoder(files, boundary='-----------------------------7652580604126525371226493196')

burp0_headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0", "Accept": "*/*", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Referer": "https://translate.yandex.com/", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------7652580604126525371226493196", "Origin": "https://translate.yandex.com", "DNT": "1", "Connection": "close"}

print(requests.post(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers, files=m.to_string()).text)
```

though sadly it yields the following output:

```
{"error":"BadArgument","description":"Bad argument: file"}
```

Does anyone know how this could be solved?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would not reproduce the boundary for the multipart upload here even. I certainly would not reproduce every single header either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you very much for your quick reply. how would you reproduce it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `MultipartEncoder.to_string()` result to the `files` parameter. You are now asking requests to encode the result of the multipart encoder to a multipart component. That's one time too many.

You don't need to replicate every byte here, just post the file, and *perhaps* set the user agent, referer, and origin:

```
files = {
    'file': ("blob", open("image_path", 'rb'), "image/jpeg")
}

url = "https://translate.yandex.net:443/ocr/v1.1/recognize?srv=tr-image&sid=9b58493f.5c781bd4.7215c0a0&lang=en%2Cru"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0", 
    "Referer": "https://translate.yandex.com/",
    "Origin": "https://translate.yandex.com",
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(response.status)
print(response.json())
```

The *Connection* header is best left to requests, it can control when a connection should be kept alive just fine. The *Accept** headers are there to tell the server what your client can handle, and `requests` sets those automatically too.

I get a 200 OK response with that code:

```
200
{'data': {'blocks': []}, 'status': 'success'}
```

However, if you don't set additional headers (remove the `headers=headers` argument), the request *also* works, so Yandex doesn't appear to be filtering for robots here.